# Hosting ASP.NET Core API in a Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Background: I am working on a project that involves a WinForms app. The client wants to expose a local-only HTTP server to allow other apps to trigger functionality on a running instance of the WinForms app via a REST API (or similar). The preference is to implement the aforementioned API using ASP.NET Core.

My question is thus: How do I structure a project to have both an ASP.NET Core API and a WinForms GUI in the same process? Are there any pitfalls I'd have to be wary of?

Comment: Why do you want to run both programs in the same process?

Comment: @citronas *to allow other apps to trigger functionality on a running instance of the WinForms app via a REST API*, Basically an inter-process communication.

Comment: @Matthew Questions which start with "*What is the best way ...*" are usually off-topic because they are opinion based. Do you have any specific question about a specific problem?

Comment: @RezaAghaei Sorry, replace "what is the best way" with "how do I"... Although, given that the vast majority of programming questions have more than one solution I'd argue that almost every question has an implicit "what is the best way" component :-)

Comment: @citronas Exactly as Reza Aghaei answered - IPC. And it's not so much "both programs" as it is two different interfaces to the same program.

Comment: Doing this makes no sense.  Even if you run both under the same process... What kind of "interaction" would it have between them?  This breaks all sorts of architecture principals and best practices.  Encapsulation, Single Responsibility, Layer Design, proper tier design.

Comment: As for pitfalls.... The threading model are probably very different so things might not end up working as you might expect.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro Just to clarify, the client wants to do it to facilitate one-way IPC between the main app and a number of "separate but related" apps. It's not my first choice for IPC, but it's not exactly breaking any more architectural principals than any other method of IPC, either. Can you elaborate please?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**Hosting ASP.NET CORE API in a Windows Forms Application and Interaction with Form**

Here is a basic step by step example about how to create a project to host ASP.NET CORE API inside a Windows Forms Application and perform some interaction with Form.

To do so, follow these steps:

1. Create a Windows Forms Application name it `MyWinFormsApp`
2. Open `Form1` in design mode and drop a `TextBox` on it.
3. Change the `Modifiers` property of the `textBox1` in designer to `Public` and save it.
4. Install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` package
5. Install `Microsoft.AspNetCore` package
6. Create a `Startup.cs` file in the root of the project, and copy the following code:

   ```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    namespace MyWinFormsApp
    {
        public class Startup
        {
            public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
            {
                Configuration = configuration;
            }
            public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
            {
                services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
            }
            public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
            {
                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                }
                app.UseMvc();
            }
        }
    }
   ```
7. Copy the following code in `Program.cs`:

   ```
    using System;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

    namespace MyWinFormsApp
    {
        public class Program
        {
            public static Form1 MainForm { get; private set; }

            [STAThread]
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsync();

                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                MainForm = new Form1();
                Application.Run(MainForm);
            }

            public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
                WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .UseStartup<Startup>();
        }
    }
   ```
8. Create a folder called `Controllers` in the root of the project.
9. Create `ValuesController.cs` in the `Controllers` folder and copy the following code to file:

   ```
    using System;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

    namespace MyWinFormsApp.Controllers
    {
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
        [ApiController]
        public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
        {
            [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult<string> Get()
            {
                string text = "";
                Program.MainForm.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    text = Program.MainForm.textBox1.Text;
                }));
                return text;
            }

            [HttpGet("{id}")]
            public ActionResult Get(string id)
            {
                Program.MainForm.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    Program.MainForm.textBox1.Text = id;
                }));
                return Ok();
            }
        }
    }
   ```
10. Run the application.
11. Type "hi" in the `textBox1`
12. Open browser and browse http://localhost:5000/api/values → You will see `hi` as response.
13. http://localhost:5000/api/values/bye → You will see `bye` in `textBox1`

**Further Reading**

You may also be interested in [How to use Dependency Injection (DI) in Windows Forms (WinForms)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70476716/3110834)

Comment: The example uses GET methods just to keep thing simple for test in browser. You may want to use different verbs based on your requirements.

Comment: This is not about best practices, it's about quick start and a simple PoC showing what you can do.

Comment: Thanks Reza. Do you know if this approach will cause any issues with the threading model?

Comment: As I mentioned in the comments, the answer is not about best practices, it's more a PoC, however there are some points about this solutions: (1) In general, the idea is OK, it's inter-process communication. (2) I have used a similar approach using WCF for IPC between WinForms applications in a production environment without any problem. (3) I used ASP.NET WEB API for this purpose in test environments, but I haven't used ASP.NET CORE for this purpose yet. (4) As long as you use Invoke to access UI thread, there is no problem to try to access to UI thread.

Comment: Another option to consider, you can think of using MSMQ or any other message bus to communicate between the applications in an event/message based solution. (which is out of scope of this post)

Comment: If I gave it more try, I'll let you :)

Comment: Thank you Reza, your answer works like a charm.

Comment: @mortezajafari Awesome! Glad to hear that worked for you!

Comment: When its an async method which also returns a result use:
            test = Program.MainForm.Invoke(new Func<Task<string>>(async () =>
                {
                    return await Task.FromResult(await Program.MainForm.ParseOrderbookAsync());
                })).Result;

Comment: Thanks for your code, but not support NuGet packages higher than 2, 
System.MethodAccessException: 'Attempt by method 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration issue

Comment: @ZanyarJ.Ahmed I cannot remember the version of .NET which I used for this code. But I'll probably update the steps for .NET 6 once I find time. And the packages are the same package as you use in a ASP.NET CORE project.

Comment: @Ruyut updated for .NET 6

Answer (score 3):

I Install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore` package can't use

I look at this [WebApplication.CreateBuilder Method Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication.CreateBuilder?view=aspnetcore-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-6.0) find need Microsoft.AspNetCore.dll, but I can't use this.

I hope it helps others.

---

Install [Microsoft.AspNetCore.App](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App) package

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App --version 2.2.8
```

the Minimal API:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication app = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication.Create(new string[] { });
app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");
app.RunAsync();
```

Ok, now you can open `http:localhost:5000` to look `Hello World!`

*Because few people will use parameters in WinForm, `string[] args` is omitted here, and `new string[] { }` is used instead*

---

If you want to ues controller, like ASP.NET Core, then you can use this:

```
var builder = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new string[]{});
builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();
app.MapControllers();
app.RunAsync();
```

HomeController.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace RuyutWinFormsApi;

[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok("This is a test api");
    }
}
```

you can open `http://localhost:5000/api/home` to look `This is a test api`

BTY, if you want to change port, you can add this:

```
app.Urls.Add("http://0.0.0.0:8080");
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a class I made to do this. Basically I created a function in the .NET 6.0 Web API Controller starting template.

```
public async Task Listen(IServiceCollection services, List<Type> controllers, int port, CancellationToken token)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
    builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options => options.Listen(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port));
    // Add services to the container.

    builder.Services.AddControllers();
    // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

    builder.Services.Add(services);
    //builder.Services.AddSingleton<HostedCheckoutService>(hc);

    // Add our external card processor controller. This mocks a web page that is returned
    // in the Hosted Checkout iframe.
    //var assembly = typeof(LocalCardProcessorController).Assembly;
    foreach (var controller in controllers)
    {
        var assembly = controller.Assembly;
        builder.Services.AddControllers().PartManager.ApplicationParts.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.AssemblyPart(assembly));
    }

    var app = builder.Build();

    //Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (true)//app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        // Need to manually navigate to http://127.0.0.1:16600/swagger/index.html
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "MyAPI V1"));
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());
           
    await app.RunAsync(token);
    await app.DisposeAsync();

}
```

Call it in your form like so;

```
APIServer server = new APIServer();

var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<SomeService1>();
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<SomeService2>();
server.Listen(serviceCollection, new() { typeof(SomeController1), typeof(SomeController2) }, 9001, new CancellationToken());
```

Note Swagger is using **Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (6.3.0)**