# Can WinForms have dependencies injected without using a dependency injection framework?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dependency-injection, constructor-injection

I've read through many question on dependency injection in WinForms, with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70475830/how-to-use-dependency-injection-in-winforms) being the most popular one. I was shocked to discover that every example I've seen on this website uses a library for this job, such as `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`. This gives me my question: Can WinForms have dependencies injected without using a dependency injection framework?

For example, suppose that I have `Form1` and `Form2`. Opening the application opens `Form1`. `Form1` has a single button, which opens `Form2`. Both forms must have a `SqlConnection` injected. Can this be done without a dependency injection framework? For example, what forbids us from using plain-old constructor injection? I would expect `Application.Run(new Form1(MySqlConnectionHere))` to work in `Main()`

Comment: Nobody is stopping you from *injecting* anything in a custom Constructor, so it's not clear what you're asking, IMO -- Not related to Dependency Injection, though

Comment: **Yes**, you can perform DI without an IoC container just by supplying the dependencies yourself in the constructor. It gets a little tricky when the dependencies themselves have dependencies, so people tend to use an IoC container, but it certainly isn't mandatory.

Comment: DI is a [design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). period. A DI framework is just a tool that will reduce the boilerplate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

See Mark Seemann's [Pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/) concept.