A registered service is null in a nested user control
I have a couple of nested usercontrols, and in the innermost one, I'm getting a null ref on a service method. The service is registered, so I think it should be available. I've included a sample of my code structure. It's been a while since I've done webforms like this. It's probably a simple mistake.
If I need to provide more please message me before downvoting.
Global.asax.cs
    void RegisterCoreDependencies(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<MyService>().As<IMyService>();
    }

MainPage.aspx
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="myListControl" 
        Src="ListControl.ascx" %>
    <uc:myListControl id="ucListControl" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>

ListControl.ascx
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="myParams" 
    Src="ParameterControl.ascx" %>
<div>
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" 
                  ID="rptParameters"
                  OnItemDataBound="rptParameters_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            ... some stuff
            <uc:myParams
                ID="ucMyParams"
                HeaderText=""
                ShowAddButton="False"
                runat="server" />
            ... some other stuff
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>

ListControl.ascx.cs
    protected void rptParameters_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
         if (e.Item.FindControl("ucMyParams") is LocationParameters ucMyParams)
         {
             ucMyParams.KeyId = key.Id.ToString();
             ucMyParams.DataBind();
         }
    }

ParameterControl.ascx.cs
public partial class LocationParameters : UserControl
{
    public IMyService MyService { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Some other stuff sets parsedSampleId
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            ReloadGridview(parsedSampleId);   
        }
    }

    void ReloadGridview(int parsedSampleId)
    {
        // Here MyService is null
        var sample = MyService.GetById(parsedSampleId);
    }
}


You need to resolve the interface somehow from the container. I think the easiest way is to do it by constructor injection, but then you need to resolve your application entry point as well from the container, otherwise it cannot be resolved. You can have a look at this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70475830/how-to-use-dependency-injection-in-winforms
