# Is it possible to run a DOTNET Core WebAPI asynchronously in an AvaloniaUI Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, avaloniaui

I'm working on a project where I'm creating an AvaloniaUI frontend which would be able to be managed remotely via a REST API. In order to solve this, I created an Avalonia application, then added an additional project to the solution using the 'ASP.NET Core API' template.

I used the following question as a template for setup:

[Hosting ASP.NET Core API in a Windows Forms Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60033762/hosting-asp-net-core-api-in-a-windows-forms-application)

Here they have a similar use case, however with a winforms project rather than Avalonia.

Program.cs:

[image]

Startup.cs

[image]

When the API project starts async, the server doesn't seem to be running as it refuses the connection. The only way I have been able to get it to respond to get requests has been to set the API project as the startup project (before I had made the changes to Program.cs).

Any help at all will be appreciated, I'm relatively inexperienced when it comes to ASP.NET, so I apologise if this is a relatively simple issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.
Turns out that the server was successfully running, however due to the fact that I didn't have and SSL certificate, the server would not accept the connection except on the unsecured 5001 port.