# getter setter can't change textBox.Text control value in Winform c#

Tags: c#, winforms, getter, setter

Why textBox3.text do not shows value _TextBoxRequestMsg. MessageBox opens and shows _TextBoxRequestMsg value OK, console prints too.

```
public partial class F_Main : Form
{
    private string _TextBoxRequestMsg;

    public string TextBoxRequestMsg
    {
        get { return textBox3.Text; }
        set
        {
            _TextBoxRequestMsg = value;
            MessageBox.Show(_TextBoxRequestMsg);       
            Console.WriteLine(_TextBoxRequestMsg);    
            textBox3.Text = _TextBoxRequestMsg;         
        }
    }

    public F_Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class CdataController : ApiController
{
    F_Main mainForm = new F_Main();

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostPayloadEventsOp(string SN, string table, string OpStamp)
    {
        using (var contentStream = await this.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        {
            contentStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(contentStream))
            {
                string results = sr.ReadToEnd();
                mainForm.TextBoxRequestMsg = results;                    
            }
        }
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StringContent("OK", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        response.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue()
        {
            MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)
        };
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: "fails" is not a sufficient description of the problem you're seeing. What *actually happens*? Can you provide a [mcve]? Is the setter being executed on the right thread?

Comment: textBox3.Text is not set and new value is not visible on the Winform

Comment: MessageBox opens and shows new value, that is works

Comment: explain more. is textbox3 accessible in your class? what do you mean exactly "fails"?

Comment: Please edit the question to provide the information, instead of just using comments. (And make sure you give information about the threading aspect.)

Comment: This setter is executed inside ApiController.

Comment: `This setter is executed inside ApiController` your api knows the TextBox of an winforms ui?

Comment: You may want to read this very thoroughly: [Hosting ASP.NET Core API in a Windows Forms Application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60033762/1220550). It seems you want to do the same thing, and in it you'll find an Answer that explains how it can be done. Just creating a random `F_Main` object isn't going to cause it to magically appear anywhere, and neither will it magically connect to an `F_Main` instance that may already be visible.

Comment: But where is magic that Console.WriteLine(_TextBoxRequestMsg);  and MessageBox.Show(_TextBoxRequestMsg); shows value correctly ?

Comment: Well, the console is effectively a singleton, and MessageBox.Show creates a *new* message box. So in neither case are we creating a new, unseen window where the change could be effective but unobserved - which you *are* doing with the `F_Main` form.

Answer (score 0):

Your question states that your goal is to **change textBox.Text control value in Winform** and your code indicates that you want to do this by processing an `HttpResponseMessage`. Consider that the `Form` that owns the `textBox3` control could await the response so that it can meaningfully process its content and assign the value to the text box.

---

For a minimal example, mock the API request:

```
public class MockCdataController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MockPostPayloadEventsOp(string SN, string table, string OpStamp)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://stackoverflow.com/q/75310027/5438626"); 
            response.Content = new StringContent("OK", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            response.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue()
            {
                MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)
            };
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

---

The `Form` that is in possession of `textBox3` could invoke something like this:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        buttonPost.Click += onPost;
    }
    private async void onPost(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            UseWaitCursor = true;
            buttonPost.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
            var response = await _controller.MockPostPayloadEventsOp("38D6FF5-F89C", "records", "Asgard");
            if((response.Headers != null) && (response.Headers.CacheControl != null))
            {
                textBox3.Text = $"{response.Headers.CacheControl.MaxAge}";
            }  
        }
        finally
        {
            UseWaitCursor = false;
            Cursor.Position = new Point(Cursor.Position.X + 1, Cursor.Position.Y);
        }
    }
    MockCdataController _controller = new MockCdataController();
}
```

[image: acquire]