# Ensure form is always displayed top most when created via ControllerBase

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-6.0

I have a C# `WinForms` application that utilises a `ControllerBase` to handle interaction with a Google Chrome extension.

When a result is received, I would like to display a `Form`. However, even though I set the `Form` to be `TopMost`, along with other variations such as `BringToFront()`, the `Form` non-deterministically either displays 'TopMost', and is displayed to the user as expected, or sits in the taskbar and the user then has to click the opened `Form` in the taskbar to then bring it to front and focus. I cannot describe the behaviour better than sometimes the `Form` shows as expected (i.e. top most), and other times it does not (i.e. it opens but sits in the taskbar).

How can I ensure the `Form` always displays top most to the user?

For additional context, there is another `Form`, we'll call `MainForm` that is also running and contains the `ControllerBase` logic. The `MainForm` is not always necessarily in view or focus, but is running.

```
[Route("api/example")]
[ApiController]
public class MinimalExampleController : ControllerBase
{
    [Route("sendcontent")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult OnResultReceived()
    {
        Form form = new Form();
        form.TopMost = true;
        form.BringToFront();
        form.Focus();
        
        form.ShowDialog();
        
        return Ok(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up following a similar solution as seen at
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60046440/2215712

I put all the GUI-related logic (the `Form` I wanted to show) in a method within the `MainForm`. The `Form` now always displays and is top most.

```
public IActionResult OnResultReceived()
{
     Program.MainForm.Invoke(new Action(() =>
     {
           //ShowForm is a static method that creates and shows the Form      
           MainForm.ShowForm();
     }));
     return Ok();
}
```